# SPFolder versions?

Tags: document-library, 2013, versioning, folder, version-history

I am using SharePoint 2013 Server. I have a document library with enabled versioning. 
`SPFolder.Item.Versions` always returns only one last version of the folder item despite it was modified multiple times. `SPFolder.Item.Versions.Count` always is equal to 1.

How can I get all versions of `SPFolder` (or `SPFolder.Item`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SharePoint doesn't support multiple versions of folders in Lists and Libraries.

Comment: Any reference source?

Comment: MSDN and TechNet don't seem to specifically indicate this anywhere, but @Per Jakobsen is correct.  SharePoint offers no version functionality on folders in lists and libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The only property of a folder that you can change in the UI is the title. Changing this property doesn't update the version, and, the Version History button is greyed out for folders. So SP certainly doesn't track versions of folders out of the box, I don't know if it's possible to do something with an event receiver in code to forcibly update it or not.

[Document Sets](http://www.sharepointstories.com/2011/04/document-sets.html) have versioning capability and may suit your requirements, though they are not available in Foundation if that is what you are using. I've not seen something authoritative that says "Folders don't support versions", but it's certainly implied that that's something that document sets give you that folders don't.

Comment: No, I can have more than one field in folder content type. I can add fields from site columns to it. So there must be another reason why SP doesn't track versions of folders.

Comment: How are you adding fields to the folder?

Comment: There I found a guide for SharePoint 2007 http://www.sharepoint-guru.com/2007/06/adding-metadata-to-folder.html
But it's the same in newer versions.