# Versioning with folders and document sets?

Tags: document-set, versioning

According to [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69723/spfolder-versions) SharePoint doesn't version folders. Is the same true of Document Sets? I know there is a ribbon command to manually capture a version of a document set, but does nothing happen automatically when the document set item is changed? I have custom document set content types and custom folder content types in my library which have various metadata fields. Versions are not being created when these fields are edited. Is this working as intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use document sets and versioning you should be aware of this:

1. If the version of a document inside a document set changes, the version of the document set remains unchanged.
2. Versioning of a document set can be done manually (by using the document set's ribbon)
3. Versioning of a document set is like creating a snapshot

http://www.sharepointeurope.com/blog/2013/5/2/sharepoint-2013-versioning-and-document-sets

Comment: None of those point really address the issue? It's not about the document inside changing, it's about the document set item's fields changing. Does "can be done manually" actually mean "can only be done manually"?

Comment: Yes as per my research.

Comment: Even if you think logically this behavior is correct. SharePoint has no clue when a new version to be created (because it is dealing with multiple items)

Comment: It is dealing with one item. I don't see how the states of items grouped under it being undetermined precludes versioning the item itself.